# Final word in a string always starts on new line (issue with my extension method)

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, char

The extension method below works as it should for me, except it always puts the last word of the input string on its own line... even if the previous line has enough char spaces for it to fit.

For example, if I inputted...

```
NewSplit("apple banana carrot", 20)
```

...the output would be "apple banana " on Line 1 and "carrot" on Line 2.

It's probably something simple but I can't get my head around why it's doing this! Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

```
//split a long string into seperate lines ONLY where there are spaces
// - does not begin a new line half way through a word
public static IEnumerable<string> NewSplit(this string @this, int lineLength)
{
    var currentString = string.Empty;
    var currentWord = string.Empty;

    //for each individual character
    foreach(var c in @this) 
    {
        //if character is a space between words
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) 
        {
            //if the current word and current string on the current line
            //is greater than the line character length
            if(currentString.Length + currentWord.Length > lineLength) 
            {
                //return the current string without adding the extra word
                yield return currentString; 
                //empty the currentString variable
                currentString = string.Empty; 
            }
            //add the space character and the current word to the currentString
            currentString += c + currentWord; 
            //empty the currentWord variable
            currentWord = string.Empty; 
            continue;
        }

        //add the current character to the currentWord string
        currentWord += c; 
    };

    // The loop might have exited without flushing the last string and word...
    yield return currentString; 
    yield return currentWord;
}
```

Comment: Just as a bit of a background... The purpose of this extension is to separate extremely long strings into an array of shorter strings that fit on a single line in a rectangle. I understand that there are probably better ways to achieve this however this works fine for me asides from this small issue!

Comment: Did you try to debug the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made 2 changes to your method:

1. Switched `IsWhiteSpace` if with `currentWord += c`.
2. You need to check if your last, non-printed pair of `currentWord` and `currentString` can be returned together.

```
//split a long string into seperate lines ONLY where there are spaces
// - does not begin a new line half way through a word
public static IEnumerable<string> NewSplit(string @this, int lineLength)
{
    var currentString = string.Empty;
    var currentWord = string.Empty;

    //for each individual character
    foreach (var c in @this)
    {
        //add the current character to the currentWord string
        currentWord += c;

        //if character is a space between words
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            //if the current word and current string on the current line
            //is greater than the line character length
            if (currentString.Length + currentWord.Length > lineLength)
            {
                //return the current string without adding the extra word
                yield return currentString;
                //empty the currentString variable
                currentString = string.Empty;
            }
            //add the space character and the current word to the currentString
            currentString += currentWord;
            //empty the currentWord variable
            currentWord = string.Empty;
            continue;
        }
    };

    // print last line combined if length is less or equal to line length limit
    if (currentString.Length + currentWord.Length <= lineLength)
    {
        yield return currentString + currentWord;
    }
    else
    {

        yield return currentString;
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentWord))
            yield return currentWord;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. That makes perfect sense and I just tried it out then and it works perfectly. Can't thank you enough! I really appreciate your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more concise implementation of this functionality if you're interested.  I believe it does what you're after.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> NewSplit(this string inputString, int maxLineLength)
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    foreach(string word in inputString.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        //maybe throw an exception or something if a word with length > lineLength is encountered
        if((line + word).Length + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) ? 0 : 1) > maxLineLength)
        {
            yield return line;
            line = word;
        }
        else
        {
            line += string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) ? word : (" " + word);
        }
    }
    yield return line;
}
```